# SQL server client unable to show object hints when inputting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Not sure when I came to this issue, but now it seems all object hints (table/column name, declared variable, system pre-set functions) are no longer hinted when inputting queries in SSMS 2008R2/2012/2014 (I have all 3 clients installed in local). Sometimes even simplest syntax errors (like `SELCT 1`) are not underlined. The remote server is SQL Server 2014 and seems it works everything normal on its client. How can I solve this problem in my local client?

Answer (score 0):

The feature is called IntelliSense. It will be disabled if you have SQLCMD mode on for example. Try this guide for troubleshooting it: 
[Troubleshooting IntelliSense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/troubleshooting-intellisense)